# Efficiently split rectangle given by top left and bottom right coordinates into smaller rectangles

Tags: r

I have a rectangle given by latitude and longitude for the top left and bottom right corners of the said rectangle. I would like to split this rectangle into several smaller rectangles. The smaller rectangles should be also given by coordinates for the top left and bottom right corner.

So far, i can create the smaller rectangles by creating a placeholder list and then  running a nested for loop.

I do not think this is an efficient solution and would like to make the code more efficient.

The output should be preferably a `list` or `data.table`. Each row of the `data.table` could have 4 columns specifying the coordinates.

**My code so far:**

```
# the big rectangle i want to split
big_rectangle <- list(top_left = c("lat" = 50.183297, "lon" = 14.223024),
                      bottom_right = c("lat" = 49.945189, "lon" = 14.706829))

# sequence along the sides of the rectangle:
lat <- seq(from = big_rectangle[["bottom_right"]]["lat"],
           to = big_rectangle[["top_left"]]["lat"], length = 20)
lon <- seq(from = big_rectangle[["top_left"]]["lon"],
           to = big_rectangle[["bottom_right"]]["lon"], length = 20)

# create a list of small rectangles, each given by its top left and bottom right corners:
holder <- vector("list", (length(lat) - 1) * (length(lon) - 1))
iterator <- 1
for (i in 1:(length(lat) - 1))
{
  for (j in 1:(length(lon) - 1))
  {
    holder[[iterator]] <- list(top_left = c("lat" = lat[i + 1], "lon" = lon[j]), bottom_right = c("lat" = lat[i], "lon" = lon[j+1]))
    iterator = iterator + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Ups, there is a typo in the sample code. working on a fix

Comment: The example should be fixed now.

Comment: So you're trying to find every rectangle that has vertices at some combination of `lat` and `lon`?

Comment: Not every. I just need to break down the big rectangle into some smaller, non overlapping rectangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same basic idea as Halvorsen, but as the coordinates of interest are all spaced apart in a predictable manner, doing matching seemed a little wasteful.

```
width <- 5
height <- 4

brm <- do.call(cbind, big_rectangle)
lat <- seq(brm[1, 1], brm[1, 2], length.out=width+1)
lon <- seq(brm[2, 1], brm[2, 2], length.out=height+1)

eg <- expand.grid(lon=lon, lat=lat)

lr <- eg[-(1:(width+1)),]
ul <- eg[1:(nrow(eg)-(width+1)),]

corners <- cbind(upper_left=ul, lower_right=lr)
corners <- corners[1:nrow(corners) %% width != 0,]
rownames(corners) <- NULL
head(corners)

#   upper_left.lon upper_left.lat lower_right.lon lower_right.lat
# 1       14.22302       50.18330        14.34398        50.13568
# 2       14.34398       50.18330        14.46493        50.13568
# 3       14.46493       50.18330        14.58588        50.13568
# 4       14.58588       50.18330        14.70683        50.13568
# 5       14.22302       50.13568        14.34398        50.08805
# 6       14.34398       50.13568        14.46493        50.08805
```

To arrange the coordinates back into a list as you had them you can do.

```
corners.l <- apply(corners, 1, 
  function(x) 
    list(upper_left=c(lon=x[[1]], lat=x[[2]]), 
        lower_right=c(lon=x[[3]], lat=x[[4]])))

corners.l[1]
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$upper_left
#      lon      lat 
# 14.22302 50.18330 

# [[1]]$lower_right
#      lon      lat 
# 14.34398 50.13568
```

And just because

```
plot(eg, cex=0, axes=FALSE)
points(corners[,1:2], pch=1, cex=2)
points(corners[,3:4], pch=16)
axis(1, unique(eg[,1]), floor(unique(eg[,1])*100)/100)
axis(2, unique(eg[,2]), floor(unique(eg[,2])*100)/100)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Make all combinations of the indices, keep the ones that are a step up and a step over, then change back to the coordinates?

```
seq_lat = 1:(length(lat)-1)
seq_lon = 1:(length(lon)-1)

rectangles = expand.grid(lat1 = seq_lat, lat2 = seq_lat, lon1 = seq_lon, lon2 = seq_lon)
keeps = rectangles$lat1 + 1 == rectangles$lat2 &  rectangles$lon1 + 1 == rectangles$lon2
rectangles = rectangles[keeps,]
rectangles$lat1 = lat[rectangles$lat1]
rectangles$lat2 = lat[rectangles$lat2]
rectangles$lon1 = lon[rectangles$lon1]
rectangles$lon2 = lon[rectangles$lon2]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! That looks promising, although it seems to me some rectangles must be missing

Comment: Specifically, i think that the solution drops one column and one row that should be included

Comment: Also, i'd rather avoid the `expand.grid` in this form. It creates an object which is too large

Comment: I think this might work though. First: `rectangles = expand.grid(lat1 = seq_lat,lon1 = seq_lon)`, then: `rectangles$lat_br = lat[rectangles$lat1]` and `rectangles$lat_tl = lat[rectangles$lat1 + 1]` and `rectangles$lon_br = lon[rectangles$lon1 + 1]` and `rectangles$lon_tl = lon[rectangles$lon1]`

Comment: Yeah that seems nicer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I opted for the following solution to the problem. It is inspired by the Svenhalvorson's answer in the use of `expand.grid` function. Moreover it avoids using unnecessary combinations and output is a `data.table`:

```
# load data.table library
library(data.table)
# create the large bounding box
big_rectangle <- list(top_left = c("lat" = 50.183297, "lon" = 14.223024),
                      bottom_right = c("lat" = 49.945189, "lon" = 14.706829))

# split the rectangle into smaller pieces
lat <- seq(from = big_rectangle[["bottom_right"]]["lat"], to = big_rectangle[["top_left"]]["lat"], length = 20)
lon <- seq(from = big_rectangle[["top_left"]]["lon"], to = big_rectangle[["bottom_right"]]["lon"], length = 20)

# index of the lon and lat vectors
seq_lat = 1:(length(lat)-1)
seq_lon = 1:(length(lon)-1)

# create combinanations of indices and store as data.table
rectangles = data.table(expand.grid(lat1 = seq_lat,lon1 = seq_lon))

# store the coordinates of small rectangles into data.table
rectangles[, `:=`(lat_br = lat[lat1],
                  lon_tl = lon[lon1],
                  lat_tl = lat[lat1 + 1],
                  lon_br = lon[lon1 + 1]
                  )]
```